# Redirect a url with only some get params in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-2.1

I am developing an application that should still respond to some old urls from a previous web application. I would like to build some redirects to an action only when a param(get param) is present. for instance

```
get '/students/:id?school_id=(:id)', to: redirect { |params, req|
     # path of the a known action here
}
```

How will it recognize urls like this:

`/students/:id?school_id=25957`,

but NOT urls like this:

`/students/:id?address=345`